# Web Scrape: How to get all name and price from all this link?

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping

Hello Friends i am trying to all get all data like name price and another data from this all links i get all a href link in python but i don't know how to get at once all the name and price i am trying to get but i am getting error i can only print all link from this code but i need all the data from this link(name, price, another) , Please help me how to do this here is my code.

```
url='https://m.autocentrum.pl/nowe/'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

# To download the whole data set, let's do a for loop through all a tags
for i in range(80,len(soup.findAll('a'))+1): #'a' tags are for links
    one_a_tag = soup.findAll('a')[i]
    link = one_a_tag['href']
    download_url = 'http://m.autocentrum.pl'+ link

#    urllib.request.urlretrieve(download_url,+link[link.find("div", class_="car-offer")+1:]) 



#     for i in range(len(soup1.findall("div"))):
#         name = download_url.find("div", class_="new-car-header")[i]
#         print(name)
#     page = requests.get(download_url)
#     soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

#     rating = soup.find_all("div", class_="car-offer") # this is the main div inside this div all data it is so how to export in csv file

#     last_links = soup.find(class_='car-offer')
#     last_links.decompose()
    #name = soup.find(class_='new-car-header')
#     last_links = download_url.find(class_='car-offer')
#     last_links.decompose()
#     name = download_url.find(class_='new-car-header')
#     price = download_url.find(class_='mobile-car-price')
#     extra = more-info
#     artist_name_list_items = artist_name_list.find_all('a')

#urllib.request.urlretrieve(download_url,'./'+link[link.find('/turnstile_')+1:]) 
    print(download_url)
    time.sleep(1) #pause the code for a sec
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is use CSS selectors to select the right elements and the `zip()` function to tie them together:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get('https://www.autocentrum.pl/nowe/').text, 'html.parser')

print('{:<20}{}'.format('Name', 'Price'))
print('-' * 30)
for name, price in zip(soup.select('.car-offer h2'), soup.select('.car-offer div.price .number')):
    name, price = name.get_text(strip=True), price.get_text(strip=True, separator=' ')
    print('{:<20}{}'.format(name, price))
```

Prints:

```
Name                Price
------------------------------
Opel Astra          85 200 PLN
Fiat Doblo          84 800 PLN
Nissan NV200        57 310 PLN
```

Comment: why am i getting only 3 data not more @AndrejKesely

Comment: @rahulraj When I visit https://www.autocentrum.pl/nowe/ I see only 3 cars there, so that's why only 3 results

Comment: in down there is all car brand name and i need all the car list with name and price of all brand car@AndrejKesely Please Help me brother i need to do this

Comment: @rahulraj All I can say is you have to get all links for each of the car-brand, do new request for each brand and scrape the car info there.

Comment: I can not do at once is it not possible ? @AndrejKesely